# About PCIe bus enumeration without IO map

Tags: memory, pci-express, io

I'm a beginner starting to under stand PCIe protocol and I have a question about enumeration of PCIe.

According to PCIe spec, PCIe uses memory mapped IO (MMIO) instead of IO mapped IO.
The book introduces Enhanced mechanism for configuration read transaction using memory read to specific address.

However, during enumeration, CPU requests a Vendor ID in every BDF (This is a Configuration Read request). If a Vendor ID is valid, the BDF is allocated to PCIe endpoint and CPU do configuration write to BARs to assign memory address for Configuration register.

For the first time, to request a Vendor ID, CPU uses IO write to address port (who is in IO map 0x0CF8), and IO read from data port (who is in IO map 0xCFC).
But, ARM cpu does not have IO map and also the spec says PCIe endpoint does not use IO address and it may be unsuppoted in a future version of spec.

Then, for PCIe endpoint, how to request a Vendor ID during enumeration?
I would be grateful if you could explain the enumeration process in PCIe packet without IO map.